# Xamarin.Forms Entry reading from barcode reader with enter key gives empty result

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.entry

I have a problem that is happening in Xamarin Forms UWP and perhaps also will happen in Android and iOS.

I have on XAML side a entry text field called for example textEntry.

I have on code side the definition textEntry.Completed += textEntry_Completed

on my textEntry_Completed I should have the content of the textEntry.Text.

When I write via keyboard something and press return, on the textEntry_Completed I get the textEntry.Text value correctly.

When I use a barcode scanner with keyboard emulation that after reading is also appending a return code, I get a textEntry.Text empty string inside the textEntry_Completed.

How can I solve this situation ?

Thanks,
Paulo

Comment: Could you show some codes that you're using now ?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you managed to solve the issue ??